# How do I add a space in an XML schema element?

Tags: xml, xsd

How do I add a space in an XML schema element? I'd like to have "Last Name" without using an underscore. Thanks.

```
<xs:element name="Last Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. That would go against the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/). The space character is used as a delimiter in XML and has special meaning. It cannot appear in element names.

Think about the resulting element that you would be defining with that declaration:

```
<Last Name attribute1="value" attribute2="value">Contents</Last Name>
```

That doesn't look anything like XML and would be rejected by any XML parser.

Comment: You could do a dash:  Last-Name.

Answer (score 2):

this schema represents an element in XML. Elements are not allowed to have white spaces in their names as they are used as a delimiter for attributes.